# Getting each bit out of a hex/binary sequence

Tags: java

I want to give the program the variable `mesaj` as an int, either hexa or binary, but .getBytes() won't work on integers. What can I use?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int crc = 0xFFFF;       // 65535 sau 111...de 16 ori
        int polinom = 0x1021;   // 0001 0000 0010 0001  (0, 5, 12) 

        // byte[] testBytes = "123456789".getBytes("ASCII");

        String mesaj = "1111111";// I want this to be an integer
        byte[] bytes = mesaj.getBytes();//this won't work on an int

        for (int n = 0; n < bytes.length; n++) {
            byte b = bytes[n];//iau byte cu byte


            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {//iau bit cu bit al fiecarui byte

                //convertesc in sir de biti, si iau numai bitii care sunt 1
                boolean bit = ((b >> (7 - i) & 1) == 1);
                //la fel si fiecare bit al crc-ului curent
                boolean c15 = ((crc >> 15 & 1) == 1);

                crc <<= 1;


                if (c15 ^ bit) {//daca XOR pe c15 si bit da 1

                    crc ^= polinom;

                } 
            }
        }

        crc &= 0xffff;


        System.out.println("Hexa: " + Integer.toString(crc, 16));
        System.out.println("Zecimal: " + Integer.toString(crc));
        System.out.println("Binar: " + Integer.toBinaryString(crc));
    }
```

Comment: Try using java.math.BigInteger instead of int. This might get you what you want.

Comment: Then I will have a large number like "1010100111" but how can I get each byte from it like in my program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to actually parse to an `int` with e.g. `Integer.parseInt(mesaj, 2)` or `Integer.parseInt(hex, 16)` for hex numbers.

Comment: Still won't work. Integer.parseInt(mesaj, 2) will transform 101 to 5, but my program will treat it as 5, not 101, so it will use ASCII codes 49, 48, 49 instead of 1, 0, 1

Comment: Then the rest of your program is wrong, not the transformation part.  If you want to extract a bit from an `int`, you need to use something like `(x >>> index) & 1` to get a 0 or 1 from the `index`th bit.